# Showing existence of an extension for a measurable function on the whole set $X$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ \mathcal U $ be a $\sigma$-Algebra on a set $X$ and $M \subseteq X$.

Let $f:M\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be measurable in respect of the Trace-$\sigma$-Algebra $\quad \mathcal U|_M : =\{ U \cap M\mid U\in \mathcal U\}$.

**Show:** There exists an extension on whole $X$ which is also measurable

I tried to write $X = \bigcup M_i$ for $M_i \subseteq X.$

Since $f$ is measurable  for each $M_i$ then it follows that $f$ is measurable for $\bigcup M_i$ in respect to $\mathcal U|_{\bigcup M_i}.$

Therefore I can define a function $h:X \longrightarrow \mathbb R$  with $h|_M = f$ which is measurable since $f|_{M_i} $ is measurable $\forall M_i$.

I am not really sure if this is the right way so i appreciate any help on this one . Thanks

Comment: Your suggested outline doesn't make much sense to me - where do the extensions to the $M_i$ come from? Also where you say "it follows that...", it's not so clear to me that it follows.

Comment: Since $f $ is measurable for any $M \subseteq X$ I tried to write $X$ as a union of subsets of $X$. Then i wanted to follow that all functions $f_i : M_i \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ are measurable per definition. All these $f_i$ should define me a new function $h$ with domain $X = \bigcup M_i$ but I guess this is the wrong way on how to deal with that

Comment: No! You're not given that $f$ is measurable "for any $M\subset X$"! If that were so you could just let $M=X$.

Comment: I see i completely misread that... thanks

Comment: Is $M\in \mathcal U?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note you can assume that $f\ge0$, since in general $f=f_1-f_2$ with $f_j\ge0$.

Assume first that $f=\chi_E$, where $E$ is a measurable subset of $M$. Then the definition of "measurable subset of $M$" more or less gives you the extension.

So you're done if $f\ge0$ is simple. Now any positive measurable function is the limit of an increasing sequence of simple functions...

**Edit:** When I posted that I thought it was more or less a solution. On reflection maybe it's more just a suggestion of a possible approach. The detail I overlooked is this: Say $\phi_n$ is a sequence of simple funtions increasing to $f$. Say $\psi_n$ is a simple function on $X$ extending $\phi_n$. We need at least a little care to ensure that the sequence $\psi_n$ is increasing...

No problem, actually. Extend $\phi_1$ to a simple function $\psi_1$. Now $\phi_{n+1}-\phi_n$ is a non-negative simple function on $M$; the obvious method for extending simple functions extends it to a non-negative simple function $h_1$; let $\psi_2=\psi_1+h_1$. Etc.

Comment: Sorry for bothering so much but I am really confused. I understand your reasoning but I really dont know on how to conclude from this that there is an extension on X

Comment: Well, if you can arrange things so the $\psi_n$ are increasing then they increase to a measurable function on $X$.

Comment: Ahh i understand. Thank you for the help